# IOS PowerPoint slide Navigation

Tags: ios

Currently i have a UIDocumentaionInteractionController to view the PowerPoint (.ppt) file. I can able to view the slide by scrolling.

The thing i need to navigate to particular slide programatically instead of scroll using NSTimer after View has been loaded.

If any one have the solution, Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIDocumentInteractionController not provide any delegate to take the completer control over the document.

It will utilize the QLPreview frame work to preview the document whatever you specified in the corresponding URL.